# Activity Up-Navigation don't work

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity which should be able to navigate up to its parent. This is how I declared it in the Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.myapp.SeminarActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" 
        android:parentActivityName="com.myapp.SeminarOverviewActivity">

        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.myapp.SeminarOverviewActivity" />

    </activity>
```

It works when I enter SeminarActivity via an Intent in SeminarOverviewActivity. But it is possible to enter SeminarActivity from an other Activity. This activity has `noHistory=true`because I do not want to go back to it via Up-Navigation. When I enter SeminarActivity form this Activity and Press back, the App ends. I also tried use `NavUtils` and added this from the android documentation:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
         Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
         if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
             // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
             // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
             TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                     // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                     .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                     // Navigate up to the closest parent
                     .startActivities();
         } else {
             // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
             // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
             NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
         }

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

but no effect. In my tests, always the else part of the above snipped is used.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is? are you pressing back? and are you expecting to get to the parent activity by doing so?

Comment: I press back in the ActionBar left corner. And I want to go to the Activity which I declared in Manifest (SeminarOverviewActivity), even if the actual Activity is not started from it.